# No ActiveRecord é obrigatório usar belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

É obrigatório que, para haver uma associação entre dois models, eu tenha `belongs_to` e `has_one`? Ou é possível usar apenas `has_one/has_many` entre os dois models, quando não necessariamente nenhum dos models pertencem a algum outro?

Exemplo:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Comment: Você pode conseguir entender melhor no guia oficial: [/association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

Comment: @DaniloCândido surgiu essa lendo justamente o Rails Guides :/ A migration do exemplo pra `has_one` por exemplo corresponde a `t.belongs_to :supplier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há obrigatoriedade mas o  seu exemplo deixa a entender que um **Article** "pertence a" uma **Category**. Então, o mais correto é usar *belongs_to :category*.

Nesse caso, o *belongs_to* requer a existência do campo *category_id* no modelo **Article**. Que é também a forma com que o *has_many* encontra os registros.

No entanto, se você deseja usar o *has_one* para que no futuro possa se transformar em *has_many*, sem problema. Terá que usar a tabela intermediária *article_categories* que fará o link entre os dois modelos e não haverá a necessidade de ter o campo *category_id* no **Article**.